# ¿Cómo abrir un modal dentro de otro modal?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un modal que manda a llamar un componente; dentro de ese componente mando a llamar otro modal.

Mi problema esta en que cuando mando a llamar el segundo modal se abre detras del modal ya abierto.

Primer modal:

```
<div id="modal1" className="modal modal-fixed-footer">
       <div className="modal-content">
           <h5 className="title">Busqueda de clientes</h5>
           <SearchClient id="Contacts" onCopy={this.onCopy.bind(this)}  className="modal-dialog responsive"/>
       </div>
       <div className="modal-footer">
           <a href="#!" className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" ><i className="material-icons">close</i>Close</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

dentro de este modal esta el componente  se abre otro modal:

```
<div id="modal2" className="modal modal-fixed-footer">
       <div className="modal-content">
           <h5 className="title">Edit Config</h5>
           { this.state.toEdit && <EditConf item={this.state.toEdit} /> }
       </div>
       <div className="modal-footer">
           <a href="#!" className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" ><i className="material-icons">close</i>Close</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, buen día.

Comment: Prueba a modificar la propiedad `z-index` de los modales, ponle una clase a cada uno, y al primero le das un `z-index` de 999 por CSS y al segundo de 1000, por ejemplo

Comment: lo hice pero no me funciono...

Comment: Tal vez ocultando el primero con `display: none` al abrir el segundo?  O `visibility:hidden` tal vez?